# How can I save a Word 2010 document so it has a thumbnail preview image in its metadata?

Tags: metadata, microsoft-word-2010

I would like to save a **Word 2010** file so that it has automatically saves a **thumbnail image of the first page**.

[These instructions](http://www.extensis.com/en/support/kb_article.jsp?articleNumber=4902203) mention how to get **Word 2003** to save a thumbnail in the **metadata** of the .doc file:

> To save a thumbnail in Word or Excel you must go to File > Properties
>   and select the Save preview picture checkbox.

However, Word 2010 doesn't have "**File > Properties**" and under "**File > Options**" und both **Save** and **General** I find no checkbox called "Save preview".

**How can I get Word 2010 to save a thumbnail image of the first page of the document in its metadata, to be read out by other applications?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article provides step by step visual details on how to save a word document with a thumbnail: [Word 2010: Save Documents to Display with Thumbnail Picture.](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/7425/word-2010-save-documents-to-display-with-thumbnail-picture/)

If you wish to save thumbnails for all word documents by default, follow the steps given below:

1. Go to `File` > `Info` then on the right hand side of the screen click on the drop down arrow next to properties and select `Advanced Properties.`
2. In the new dialog box select the tab labelled `Summary` and the bottom of the dialog check the option to `Save Thumbnails for All Word Documents.` Then just click `OK.`