# Why doesn't Microsoft Word "Save thumbnail" work?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-starter

I tried saving a thumbnail as seen in this post: [How can I save a Word 2010 document so it has a thumbnail preview image in its metadata?](https://superuser.com/questions/322373/how-can-i-save-a-word-2010-document-so-it-has-a-thumbnail-preview-image-in-its-m) but it doesn't work - No thumbnail. Why? Is it because I have Office Starter?

New information: The thumbnails are shown when I save the file as a "word 97-2003" file. But not when I save as a "word document".

updated question: [Word 2010 saves thumbnails and tags for "Word 97-2003" only. Not for "Word documents"](https://superuser.com/questions/452658/word-2010-saves-thumbnails-and-tags-for-word-97-2003-only-not-for-word-docum)

Comment: To moderators: Please delete this question. I posted a corrected one already. Thank you.

Comment: I have reverted your edit, in future rather than deface your question either flag it for moderator attention, delete it yourself or edit it to suit your requirements.

Comment: @Mokubai I can't delete and can't flag. (I'm not registered) I didn't edit because the question changed very much. But OK, now I just edited. (My last question)