# Word 2010 saves thumbnails and tags for "Word 97-2003" only. Not for "Word documents"

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-starter

If I save a document and check the "Save thumbnail" option in the "Save as" dialog, and add a tag - both don't get saved. But if I save it as a "Word 97-2003". They do.

How to solve this?

There are a few links to .docx's that do show a thumbnail.

Comment: You obviously know you can edit questions, why aren't you simply correcting your initial question?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I didn't edit because the question changed very much. But OK, now I just edited. (My last question)

Comment: It's OK to make big changes to a question as long as what you want to know *stays the same thing*. If you need help with something **new**, just ask a new question and let the old one stay. Someone might answer it and it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've previously had this issue with my DOTX files too. A 'hack' I've found is to save the file as macro-enabled (DOCM), then save it as DOTX. After doing this, it shows the thumbnail. It's not the actual fix, but it does the job for me.